# PS command ouput with fixed width for each column

Tags: unix, solaris, aix

I am trying to execute some PS commands on IBM AIX and Solaris. The output I get is not properly formatted, I want to see the values for each column with some fixed width.

Is there anyway I can mention width for each column that PS command shows?

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual command that you're trying. `ps` output is normally aligned in columns without any extra effort. Also, show an example of what you mean by "not properly formatted".

Answer (score 4):

In GNU `ps`, you can specify the field width to widen a field:

```
ps axw o user:10,pid:8,%cpu:8,cmd
```

In Solaris and AIX, you can specify the column header to widen columns. Here, I'm padding with hyphens, but you could use something else:

```
ps -ef -o user=---USER---,pid=---PID--,%cpu=--%CPU--,cmd
```

This also works for GNU `ps`.

Comment: I am trying command "/usr/ucb/ps auxww -o user=---USER---" solaris, but I am getting error as "/usr/ucb/ps: illegal option -- o". Any clue?

Comment: @goutham: That version of `ps` doesn't have `-o`, use the other one. I believe it's `/bin/ps`.

Comment: I have to use /ucb/ps command because I want to get use,SZ, RSS and complete command for each running process. I have tried /bin/ps with some arguments but I not getting information I need. That is the reason for usuing /ucb/ps command.

Answer (score -2):

I script against a Posix complaint df which standardizes the output for both AIX and Support.

AIX: `/bin/df -kP`

SUN: `/usr/xpg4/bin/df -kP`

Comment: What does `df` have to do with `ps`?